# Prime factorizacion in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, primes

I'm making a program that, for a given integer n, returns a list of a pair of integers, where the first element is a prime from the prime factorization of n, and the second element is the corresponding exponent of that prime. For example for n = 50, it would output [(2,1),(5,2)], since 50 =(2^1)*(5^2).

So anyway, this is my code:

```
--returns all numbers that divide x
divis :: Integer -> [Integer]
divis 1 = []
divis x = [n | n<-[2..(x-1)], mod x n == 0]

--checks if a number is prime
isprime :: Integer -> Bool
isprime 1 = False
isprime n = if divis n == [] then True else False

--list of prime numbers that divide x
facto :: Integer -> [Integer]
facto 1 = []
facto x = [n | n <- (divis x), isprime n == True]

--finds the biggest exponent of a number m that divides another number n
potencia :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
potencia _ 0 = error "error"
potencia _ 1 = error "error"
potencia n m = (head [x | x <- [0..], not(mod n (m^x) == 0)]) - 1
```

The next step would be that, for a number n, I can put togheter in a pair for each number in facto n its corresponding exponent, and output that.
I have tried with this:

```
factorizar :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
factorizar 0 = error "nope"
factorizar 1 = [(1,1)] --This isn't accurate but I'll change it later
factorizar n = [(x,y) | x<-(facto n), y == potencia n x, mod n (x^y) == 0] --THIS
```

I know, the y part in the set comprehension is ugly everywhere. The thing is I dont know what to use since for defining y I need to use x as well, but it is part of the set comprehension. I have tried changing it, or using 'where' but it always has a problem with 'y', telling me it's not in the scope or something. What could be an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Style note: don't write `if divis n == [] then True else False`, just write `divis n == []` or even `null (divis n)`. Similarly, don't write `isprime n == True`, just write `isprime n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is

```
y == potencia n x
```

should really read

```
let y = potencia n x
```

and you don't need to check that `mod n (x^y) == 0` - I think it is going to be true by definition of `potencia`.

There are other things you could do differently, but they are tidy-ups.